# Google Cloud Deployment Manager and resources changes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I would like to deploy an application in Google Cloud. It would require the following Google Cloud components:

- Google Container Engine (so I can run an application inside Kubernetes cluster)
- Google Compute Engine persistent disk (attached to the application Kubernetes pods)
- Kubernetes deployment (containing the application running in the pods)

I am evaluating Deployment Manager as a tool for infrastructure as code approach.

Currently I have found following issues:

#### Changing Container Engine cluster size

Change Container Engine cluster size in my Deployment Manager yaml template cannot be applied with:

`gcloud deployment-manager deployments update <deployment-name> --config <deployment-config.yml>`

fails with:

> {"ResourceType":"container.v1.cluster","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"message":"Invalid
>   JSON payload received. Unknown name \"cluster\": Cannot find
>   field.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest","fieldViolations":[{"description":"Invalid
>   JSON payload received. Unknown name \"cluster\": Cannot find
>   field."}]}],"statusMessage":"Bad
>   Request","requestPath":"https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/1013690875001/zones/europe-west1-b/clusters/dev-cluster"}}

#### Resizing persistent disk size

When I change the disk size in my template and try to apply the change (again with `gcloud deployment-manager deployments update` command) I am also getting an error:

> No method found to update field 'sizeGb' on resource
>   'my-data-storage' of type 'compute.v1.disk'. The resource may need
>   to be recreated with the new field.

### Question

I would think the operations describe above are ones of the most common one would apply to the environment and I am surprised they are not supported.

Am I misunderstanding how Deployment Manager should be used or it just doesn't provide the features I need? How should I manage such environment changes so they can be tracked in source control (instead of imperative commands like `cloud compute disks resize`)?

Comment: FWIW, I'm having trouble doing any GKE deployments ATM using Deployment Manager, as of 2017/05/23. GIves a similar "cannot find field" error for every field I specify. This is for a brand new deployment, not an update.

Comment: @nfirvine GKE deployments via DM works fine for me (take a look at sample configs: https://gist.github.com/pbzdyl/2c3e93c54464a158beff1edb6c203a88). You can also take a look at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/gke - deployment using jinja templates work for me too. The issue is once you deploy you cannot use DM to manage the size of you cluster.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've figured out my problem. Most properties live under the cluster property instead of directly under `properties`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that the first case (resizing cluster) is an issue already reported to Google: [Updating Container Engine properties results in 400: JSON payload received. Unknown name "cluster"](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38131324)

For the second one I have also opened an issue: [Deployment Manager doesn't support persistent disk resizing](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62076314)

---

**Update**

The issue with resizing persistent disk has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is a confusing error message from GCP. There is nothing wrong with your JSON, but rather the configuration state transition cannot be updated. It would be great if this produced an `incompatible configuration update` error.

In my case, we added scopes, which it turns out cannot be updated (added or removed).